# a page shuold be open in right frame on clicking link of some page if left frame?

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am new user to php and i have a html page which is devided into two frmaes left frame and right frame and i am showing a tree list page in left frame and what i want to do is that when i click on a node of tree related link page should be open in right frame. how can i do this. plz help e out.

Comment: I believe the frames approach could be better revised into something more efficient and, need to say, *modern*.

Comment: Before I answer your question, could you answer mine: Why do you expect me to provide you with information you value, if you don't even attempt to use correct spelling and capitalization?

Comment: Its all technologies fault, texting and AIM in particular. People now a days abbreviate everything and have completely stopped spelling things out...idk y

Comment: @Anthony ... I think it is just lazy people's fault. I've used technology since I was 4 years old, n i dun typez rlly badz.

Comment: @Chacha, Very true. At least you made a difference to the OP, the first initial in the name is now capitalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your frameset, you define two `<frames>` — add a `name="X"` element to both, then in your links in your tree add `target="right_frame"` (or whatever you named your frame).

Might I strongly suggest that you consider a design that does not use frames?

Comment: +1, frames are evil, especially if you've got PHP at your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to name both frames using the name attribute, and then in the hyperlinks in the left you should specify the name of the right frame in the target attribute of the right frame.

You will find the following reference useful: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/present/frames.html#h-17.2